# Mysql date table join alternative

Tags: mysql

When data warehousing, and there is no data for a particular day, the dataset may leave a gap in dates in mysql

```
date       count
2014-07-09 1
2014-07-10 1
2014-07-11 1
2014-07-13 1
2014-07-15 1
```

When it is expected to look like:

```
date       count
2014-07-09 1
2014-07-10 1
2014-07-11 1
2014-07-12 0
2014-07-13 1
2014-07-14 0
2014-07-15 1
```

This can be solved by left joining to a table prepopulated soley with a column with every single date for every day up to a date.
However I'm wondering if there is an alternative to this in Mysql?

Comment: For what purpose do you need an alternative? Why is it not working?

Comment: It does work, I just don't think it's a good solution. For example, if the date table is forgotten about and needs populating again, then gaps will randomly start appearing one day in the future, and would be hard to diagnose.

Comment: That is true so you may need to automate populating your date table each year. You can do something in code but I doubt you can do anything in SQL

Comment: Google "mysql create event". You can simply populate your date table every year/month/day, whatever you want.

Comment: Why would you run out of dates? The overhead of storing dates right up to the year 9999 would be trivial.

Comment: It sure is trivial, but even if I didn't run out of dates, it doesn't mean it is the *best* solution.  My idea of it would be not to have to create the table at all since its a popular problem.